# How long should I wait to find out the status of my application?

Tags: interviewing

I read similar post here asking "How long should one wait to see if they got the job?".  Well...my situation is more complicated:

3 days after an interview, I was informed that I was not shortlisted. Apart from disappointment, I wrote to the interviewer and thank for her time and opportunity. Later I found out I was not chosen because they thought I was not passionate enough for the job.  So I wrote back and asked if I could be offered a second consideration, and even spoke to the interviewer on phone next morning. She said she needed to discuss with her boss and review.  A week past, shall I consider my application fail? I know it would not be appropiate to call again.

Any sharings are welcome...

Comment: "She said she needed to discuss with her boss and review"  -that's a polite way of saying "No".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> She said she needed to discuss with her boss and review. A week past,
>   shall I consider my application fail?

With all interview communications, it's best to ask "When should I check back with you?" so that you know how long the other party wants you to wait. It's unfortunate you didn't do that.

In general, a week between communications is reasonable. If you haven't heard back, now would be an appropriate time for a follow-up email. Something like "We spoke last week. You indicated that you would speak with your boss and decide if you would grant me a second consideration. Have you been able to reach a conclusion yet? ..."